# Does someone have any idea, how to get this x-scale?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scaling, fractions, percentile

It wasnt possible to get it using scale_x_continuous(trans = "log10") OR coord_trans(x = scales::exp_trans(100)).

Figure shows rain fraction by percentile

[image: Figure shows rain fraction by percentile]

Comment: Welcome to SO, nas93! Can you include sample data and code to get started with this?

Comment: Does `scales::trans_new("percentile",
                        transform = function(x) 100 - log(100 - x),
                        inverse = function(x) 100 - exp(100 - x))` do what you want?